# jquery DataTable with JSON string

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable

Hi: Straight to the point.
Im trying to pass a JSON string  from an ajax call as the datasource
PHP Code

```
if($_POST){
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    if($action == "call_data"){
        header('Content-type: application/json');  
        include_once 'clases/Usuario.class.php';  
        $usuario = new Usuario;  
        $resultado = $usuario->listar_jefes ();  
        if ( ! $resultado )  
        {  
            exit ("nok");  
        }  
        exit (json_encode ($resultado));  
    }
}
```

And my jquery code.

```
$.post("function.php", {action:"call_data"},function(jsonstr){  
    $("#usr_table").dataTable({  
        "bProcessing": true,  
        "sAjaxSource": jsonstr  
    });
});
```

But it is not working... any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I'm putting my table... just in case:

```
<table id="usr_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting a response at all? Also, you are accepting an argument jsonstr in your callback. Are you expecting that to be a string or an object?

Comment: Yes @Jage, I have a response... a json encoded string.  [code]"[{\"usuario_id\":\"37\",\"run\":\"100428725\",...[/code]

Comment: Sounds like your dataTable is not doing something right then. Are you sure it's not expecting a JSON object, and you are passing a JSON string?

Comment: I tried to parse it wiht json2.js JSON.parse(jsonstr) function but doesnt work either

Comment: Does that mean it is expecting an object then? Jquery will return it as an object to you automatically if you ask for it ( [code]$.post(url, data, callback, 'json');[/code] ). The point is though, the process is failing in dataTable(). That code as well as a full sample of the object you're getting back would be more helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @Jage. Thanks for your interest. I noticed I'm receiving an Object Array with all the data. I'm stringifying it and now i have a "No data available in table" message...

Comment: yw. Still goes back to your original problem. The dataTable function is not getting what it needs or has some other problem. The code you put in this question is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get data back at all? If so you may need to convert the data you get back to a json object.

```
var json_object = eval('(' + returned_data_string + ')');
```

Comment: Yes I'm receiving data. A JSON encoded string. I tried to parsing it with json2.js JSON.parse(jsonstr) function, but it dont help.

Comment: eval is evil!  Please avoid.